# How can I tell the each form in request?

Tags: symfony

I have simple question about formbuilder in symfony2

I am making the page which has two forms in one page.

```
    $form1 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('date1')
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'date1 INPUT!'))
    ->getForm();


    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('date2')
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'date2 INPUT!'))
    ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:formExample.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView(),'form2' => $form2->createView()));
```

then reveiving class

```
public function receiveAction(Request $request){
    $receiveForm = $this->createFormBuilder($myClass)
        $receiveForm->handleRequest($request);
            if ($receiveForm->isValid()) {
        //how can I tell this $request data is form1 or form2???
     }
}
```

I am using sumfony 2.3.19

please give me some good idea!!

---

Thanks for reply,
I think my first question is not good.
I re-write the code.
form1 has the form coorspondant class.
form2 doesn't have coorspondant class.

```
public function tPortalAction(Request $request){

    $scheTeacher = new ScheTeacher();
    $form1 = $this->createFormBuilder($scheTeacher)
    ->add('date1')     
    ->add('save1','submit', array('label'=>'date1 INPUT!')) 
    ->getForm();    

    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()     
    ->add('date2')
    ->add('save2','submit', array('label'=>'date2 INPUT!'))     -
    ->getForm();

    $form3 = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();
    $form3->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form3->isValid()) {
        if ($form3->get('save1')->isClicked()) {
            // form 1
            echo("form1 clicked!");break;
        } elseif ($form3->get('save2')->isClicked()) {
            // form 2
            echo("form2 clicked!");break;
        }    
    }
}
```

with this code
nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the user will click on the submit for one form only, you could checked to see what was clicked.
(*This is only available in Symfony >= 2.3*)

<s>Change your forms to being something like;</s>

```
$form1 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('date1')
    ->add('save1', 'submit', array('label' => 'date1 INPUT!'))
    ->getForm();


    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('date2')
    ->add('save2', 'submit', array('label' => 'date2 INPUT!'))
    ->getForm();
```

Then when checking try:

```
if ($form->get('save1')->isClicked()) {
   // form 1
} elseif ($form->get('save2')->isClicked()) {
   // form 2
}
```

Edit as per question update:

This is untested, but should work;

```
public function tPortalAction(Request $request){

    $scheTeacher = new ScheTeacher();
    $form1 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('myform1', 'form',  $scheTeacher, array())
        ->add('date1')
        ->getForm();

    $form2 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('myform2', 'form',  null, array())
        ->add('date1')
        ->getForm();

    if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        if ($request->request->has('myform1') {
            // handle the first form
        }

        if ($request->request->has('myform2') {
            // handle the second form
        }

        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your repky!. however my first explanation is quite bad,so I added the sample code, could you see that?